# How to match URL path pattern and serve filesystem resource with Apache?

Tags: apache

Could someone please tell me how to (if possible) match a URL path pattern and then serve a particular resource file if a match is found with Apache (v2.2.22).

For example, if a request arrives with the URL https://my.domain.com/abc/123 or https://my.domain.com/xyz/456 then I'd like to serve the filesystem resource `page.html`. In particular, the incoming URL should be left intact, because some Javascript at page.html will process the URL path and take appropriate action based on whether the first part of the path is `abc` or `xyz`.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I asked the question prematurely. It's fairly simple to achieve this with the mod_rewrite module e.g.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule  ^.*/(abc|xyz)/.*$  /page.html [NC]
```